# Print price of the item corresponding to different sizes and if there is no variation in size then print the base price

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my models I have created a new class variation in which I added 3 variations to my first product like small, medium, large. but what I want is to pass the price according to variation and if some product do not have any variation then it must pass the base price saved earlier in the database.

Cart App

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.

from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItem 

def view(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        context = {"cart": cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "Your Cart is Empty, please keep shopping."
        context = {"empty": True, "empty_message": empty_message}

    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def update_cart(request, id):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)
    try:
        qty = request.GET.get('qty')
        update_qty = True
    except:
        qty = None
        update_qty = False



    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product)
    if created:
        print "yeah"


    if update_qty and qty:
        if int(qty) == 0:
            cart_item.delete()
        else:
            cart_item.quantity = qty
            cart_item.save()
    else:
        pass        


    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
        line_total = float(item.product.price) * item.quantity
        new_total += line_total

    request.session['items_total'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

Products App

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=29.99)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, null=True, blank=True)

    #image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/images/', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    Product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image  = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Product.title


class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    #category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #objects = VariationManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

html block

```
{% block product%}
  <div class='row'>

  {% for product in products %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
  {% for item in product.productimage_set.all %}
      <div class="thumbnail">
   <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}" /><br>
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    <h5>{{ product.price }}</h5>
    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>

    <form method='GET' action='{% url "update_cart" product.id %}'>

    <input name='qty'  type='number' value='1' />

    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value='Add to cart'/>

    {% if product.variation_set.all %}
    <select name='size'>
    {%for item in product.variation_set.all %}
    <option value='{{ item.title|lower }}'>{{ item.title|capfirst }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

    </select>
    {% endif %}


    </form>


  </div>
 </div>


  {% endfor %}

  </div>

  {% endfor %} 

  </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not put the logic in `get_price()`?

```
def get_price(self):
    if check_for = variation
        return preferred_price
    else: 
        return self.price
```

You'd call it with `Purchase.get_price()`

If you want to speed things up, you can cache the values with a property decorator. For example:

```
@property
def adjusted_price(self):
    if check_for = variation
        return preferred_price
    else: 
        return self.price
```

This would be called with `Purchase.adjusted_price`

Comment: Here I am not getting two things one is the return preferred_price and the call i.e is Purchase.get_price could you please explain it further

Comment: This is pseudo code to show the process. You have to write the logic itself in this function to decide which related variation to retrieve a price from. I don't know how you want that to work.

Comment: the problem with the above pseudo code is that it will change the price but not according to the size

Comment: You can't check the size and return the appropriate price? Like, `if Product.variation_set.filter(size="large").count() > 0:` will check if there are any `Variation` objects with the `size` attribute set to `"large'` associated with your `Product`